# identifying windows service

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

On my win7 machine when I watch a movie in XBMC, once per hour the desktop regains the focus. The movie keeps playing, but in the background now, so I can only hear it. It is quite irritating.

I noticed, that the Windows Application log always contains two entres for this time:
"The description for Event ID 0 from source Self-service Plug-in cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer."

One entry is for starting, and one for stopping 60 seconds later. This keeps repeating, every two starts 3600 seconds apart.

How can I repair it? How can I find out which service it is?

Comment: Is there any Citrix product installed?

Comment: yes, but it has been installed several times in the last few years, and never had this problem.
Should I remove it?

Comment: The only useful google results for "self service plug in", refers to citrix products, remove it and reinstall if you need the software.

Comment: Thanks, removing it worked. I will have to wait and see if it happens again after I reinstall it.

Comment: It seems to have worked - I suggest you to answer your own question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moab suggested to remove the Citrix program. I did it, and it solved the problem.